# git looses the history trail between SVN tags

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My git repo is tracking an SVN repo. One of my git branch, let's call it 'latest_tag', points to the source code as it is in the latest SVN tag. When a new SVN tag is created, I want to merge the changes in 'latest_tag'. When I try to do this, git complains about merge conflicts, as though it had no understanding of the SVN history.

The SVN repo is using the standard structure.

```
trunk/
tags/
 - v1
branches/
```

I created my git repo the usual way.

```
git svn clone --stdlayout url_to_svn_repo git_repo
```

I created git branches for each SVN tag, and a 'latest_tag' branch.

```
git branch v1 tags/v1
git branch latest_tag v1
```

When a new tag is added in the SVN repo (e.g., v2), I can import it in my git repo.

```
git svn fetch
git branch v2 tags/v2
```

But if I try to fast-forward the 'latest_tag' branch from v1 to v2, I get an error.

```
$ git checkout latest_tag
$ git merge v2
Auto-merging source.py
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in source.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

When I look at the conflict, it looks like git considers all changes between v1 and v2 as unrelated, though they have a common history.

Here is a minimal script that recreates the issue.

```
# Create the svn repo and its first tag.
svnadmin create svn_repo/
svn checkout "file:///${PWD}/svn_repo/" svn_working_copy
( cd svn_working_copy ; mkdir -p trunk tags branches ; svn add * ; svn commit -m 'Initialize SVN repo' ; cd trunk ; echo "print 'Hello v1'" >source.py ; svn add * ; svn commit -m 'Development for v1' ; cd .. ; svn cp trunk/ tags/v1 ; svn commit -m 'Tag v1' ; sed --in-place 's/v1/v2/' trunk/* ; svn commit -m 'Development for v2' ; )

# Create a git repo from the svn repo.
git svn clone --stdlayout "file://${PWD}/svn_repo/" git_repo
( cd git_repo ; git branch v1 tags/v1 ; git branch latest_tag v1 )

# Create tag v2 in svn.
( cd svn_working_copy ; svn cp trunk/ tags/v2 ; svn commit -m 'Tag v2' )

# Merge or rebase 'latest_tag' git branch on svn tag v2.
( cd git_repo ; git svn fetch ; git branch v2 tags/v2 ; git checkout latest_tag ; git merge v2 )
```

**EDIT**
I confirm git seems to have no sense of the common history between two SVN tags.

```
$ git log --oneline master
bd050cd Development for v2
373f808 Development for v1
3b92703 Initialize SVN repo
$ git log --oneline remotes/tags/v1
31f9fff Tag v1
3b92703 Initialize SVN repo
$ git log --oneline remotes/tags/v2
b717759 Tag v2
3b92703 Initialize SVN repo
```

If git understood the SVN history, it would output this.

```
$ git log --oneline remotes/tags/v1
31f9fff Tag v1
373f808 Development for v1
3b92703 Initialize SVN repo
$ git log --oneline remotes/tags/v2
b717759 Tag v2
bd050cd Development for v2
373f808 Development for v1
3b92703 Initialize SVN repo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why git seemed to have no sense of the svn history. The answer is: it depends on how you create your svn tag.

Looking at the svn history, I saw that the svn tags were created as a composition of files from various revisions, instead of being created as a snapshot of a given revision.

```
$ svn log -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | lacton | 2013-07-27 18:15:20 | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /tags/v1 (from /trunk:1)
   A /tags/v1/source.py (from /trunk/source.py:2)

Tag v1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Although svn seems perfectly happy with this, git-svn gets confused by this.

Adding an `svn update` before doing the tag creation fixes this issue.

```
$ svn up
At revision 2.
$ svn cp trunk/ tags/v1
A         tags/v1
$ svn commit -m 'Tag v1'
Adding         tags/v1

Committed revision 3
$ svn up
At revision 3.
$ svn log -v -r HEAD
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | lacton | 2013-07-27 18:20:26 | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /tags/v1 (from /trunk:2)

Tag v1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With this fix, git-svn interprets the svn tag history correctly, and there is not a merge conflict anymore.

Here is the "git-friendly" version (i.e., with `svn update` before tag creation) of the minimal script provided with the initial question.

```
# Create the svn repo and its first tag.
svnadmin create svn_repo/
svn checkout "file:///${PWD}/svn_repo/" svn_working_copy
( cd svn_working_copy ; mkdir -p trunk tags branches ; svn add * ; svn commit -m 'Initialize SVN repo' ; cd trunk ; echo "print 'Hello v1'" >source.py ; svn add * ; svn commit -m 'Development for v1' ; cd .. ; svn up ; svn cp trunk/ tags/v1 ; svn commit -m 'Tag v1' ; sed --in-place 's/v1/v2/' trunk/* ; svn commit -m 'Development for v2' ; )

# Create a git repo from the svn repo.
git svn clone --stdlayout "file://${PWD}/svn_repo/" git_repo
( cd git_repo ; git branch v1 tags/v1 ; git branch latest_tag v1 )

# Create tag v2 in svn.
( cd svn_working_copy ; svn up ; svn cp trunk/ tags/v2 ; svn commit -m 'Tag v2' )

# Merge or rebase 'latest_tag' git branch on svn tag v2.
( cd git_repo ; git svn fetch ; git branch v2 tags/v2 ; git checkout latest_tag ; git merge v2 )
```